# I create a CSS switcher, but I need to change only elements with class="red" for body

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a CSS switcher, but I need to change only elements with `class="red"` for `body`. How can I do it?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <jdoc:include type="head" />
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="/js/modernizr-2.0.6.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.min"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="front">
        <select class="style-change">
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
        </select>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('.style-change').change(function(){
                    $('link[rel="stylesheet"]')
                        .attr("href", $(this).val() + ".css");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Demo [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/RPKSa/)

Comment: You are changing the `href` attribute of every `<link rel="stylesheet">`, I don't think this is what you want in the end. Assuming you want the class of `<body>` to be changed accordingly to your `<select>` value, `$('body').removeClass().addClass($(this).val());` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to change the body's class.

```
document.body.className="red"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer straight javascript, Moazzam's answer should do the trick. If you prefer to use jQuery, you can use this:

```
$('body').removeClass().addClass('red');
```

Or, to generalize it for use with the dropdown, this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.style-change').change(function(){
        $('body').removeClass().addClass($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the body tag class, update the jquery function:

```
$('.style-change').change(function(){
    $('body').removeClass();
    $('body').addClass($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mF9qm/